# Open Layers Styling draw interaction in polygon mode

Tags: styles, draw, polygon, openlayers-3

I'm trying to alter the default style for the draw polygon interaction.  Currently it draws a line string of blue lines, and fills in the polygon so far with a semi-transparent fill.

However if I change it, it always connects the current point to the first point.

Can anyone guide me on how this was achieved?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: You say that you want to alter the default style, but could you please be more specific about the expected behaviour? Even a picture would help.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the style for both, *Layer* and *Interaction*.

By setting the style in the Draw element, you will change the style of the polygon **while you are drawing it:**

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: source,
    type: 'Polygon',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
           color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)'
        })
    })
});
```

And changing the style for the vector layer which shares source with the Draw element, you will be modifying the style of the polygon **once it is drawn:**

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)'
        })
    })
});
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sv9z8sut/)